# Grid View begins lagging

Tags: android, scroll, android-gridview, android-scrollview, lag

I'm trying to make a simple grid view that's displays a grid of images. However, something is making the app lag extremely bad. I get a bunch of warnings about frames being skipped, and that I might be doing too much work on the main thread, but I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**My Adapter:**

```
public class HeaderListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<HeaderInfo> headerList;
    private int HEADER_SIZE;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    public HeaderListAdapter(Activity context, List<HeaderInfo> headerList) {
        this.headerList = headerList;
        HEADER_SIZE = (context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.storeItemSelect_HeaderHeight));
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final HeaderInfo headerInfo = (HeaderInfo) this.getItem(position);

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.store_item_selection_header_card, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.headerImage.setImageDrawable(headerInfo.headerImage);
        holder.headerSpace.setVisibility(position == 0 || position == 1 
            ? View.VISIBLE 
            : View.GONE);
        holder.headerName.setText(headerInfo.headerName);

        return convertView;
    }

public static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView headerImage;
    public TextView headerName;
    public Space headerSpace;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        headerImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.header_image);
        headerName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.header_title);
        headerSpace = (Space) v.findViewById(R.id.headerSpace);
    }
}

public int Height() {
    return (HEADER_SIZE + 32) * Math.round(headerList.size() / 2);
}
```

**My onCreate Activity:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.store_item_selection_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    storeName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_STORE_NAME);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    backdrop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
    collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    GridView testGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    headerItems = _HelperFunctions.getTempHeaderDB(this);
    HeaderListAdapter expandableListAdapter = new HeaderListAdapter(this, headerItems);
    testGridView.getLayoutParams().height = getHeight(expandableListAdapter.Height());
    testGridView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    testGridView.setNumColumns(2);

    setupToolbar(toolbar, collapsingToolbar, storeName, backdrop);

    LayoutAnimationController controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.recent_layout_controller);
    testGridView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
}
```

note: the `getHeight()` method simply gets the right height to set the listview, and the `setupToolbar` just sets up my collapsible toolbar.

If you need any more information let me know, and thanks for the help!

Comment: If performance is the problem, just use a profiler

Comment: If your images are very large it's going to take some time to scale them down to size. Consider scaling them on a background thread and caching the result. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

So in my case, the issue was that my images were too large which was causing stress since they were all being loaded on the UI thread. JohanShogun's advice about using a background thread and caching the result was the right approach.

[This link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) was a great start and [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency) helped me understand Async tasks and background loading.